# I referred one example from book headfirst program name guessing game but I understand the whole program but a certain part is not understood

Tags: java

The code which  not understand how guessp1 and guessp2 and guessp3 are assign p1.number and so on can some one shed light on this?

```
public class GuessGame {
    Player p1;
    Player p2;
    Player p3;
    public void startGame() {
        p1 = new Player();
        p2 = new Player();
        p3 = new Player();

        int guessp1 = 0;
        int guessp2 = 0;
        int guessp3 = 0;

        boolean p1isRight = false;
        boolean p2isRight = false;
        boolean p3isRight = false;
        int targetNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        System.out.println(“I’m thinking of a number between 0 and 9...”);

        while(true) {
            System.out.println(“Number to guess is “ + targetNumber);
            p1.guess();
            p2.guess();
            p3.guess();
            guessp1 = p1.number;          //this part is not understood
            System.out.println(“Player one guessed “ + guessp1);
            guessp2 = p2.number;          //this part is not understood
            System.out.println(“Player two guessed “ + guessp2);
            guessp3 = p3.number;         //this part is not understood
            System.out.println(“Player three guessed “ + guessp3);
            if (guessp1 == targetNumber) {
                p1isRight = true;
            }
            if (guessp2 == targetNumber) {
                p2isRight = true;
            }
            if (guessp3 == targetNumber) {
                p3isRight = true;
            }
            if (p1isRight || p2isRight || p3isRight) {
                System.out.println(“We have a winner!”);
                System.out.println(“Player one got it right? “ + p1isRight);
                System.out.println(“Player two got it right? “ + p2isRight);
                System.out.println(“Player three got it right? “ + p3isRight);
                System.out.println(“Game is over.”);
                break; // game over, so break out of the loop
            } else {
                // we must keep going because nobody got it right!
                System.out.println(“Players will have to try again.”);
            } // end if/else
        } // end loop of loop
    } // end method method end here
} // end class
```

I have added comment in front of those line which I don't understood? so please shed some light.

Comment: Please format your code properly. It hurts to read it as is.

Comment: The Players are Player() objects that uses the class Player. Do you have code for that? Apparently when you use player.guess() function, a player is asked a number from the screen and it is stored in this Players number-field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Player class has an instance variable 'number'. This variable holds the number player has guessed. You have created three objects of Player: p1, p2 and p3. Hence, when you say 'p1.number', you are accessing the number player p1 has guessed, and so on.

I assume that the guessing by each player is done in the instance method 'guess()', which is called upon individual objects p1, p2 and p3 to acquire their guesses.

Answer (score 0):

Class Player apparently has a variable called number.  It is accessible in the class you showed, by p1.number, p2.number, p3.number.

Answer (score 0):

Rant:
This is a classic example of what I like to call "monkey programming".  Not you, but the source of the example code.  p1, p2, and p3 might as well be called ITheAuthorAmAMonkey1, ITheAuthorAmAMonkey2, and ITheAuthorAmAMonkey3 because both sets of names are equally meaningful (in this case, without meaning).

Answer:
p1, p2, and p3 are three independent players of the game.  The three lines you commented are the game engine retrieving each player's guess at the number, in order.  player p1 guesses, then player p2 guesses, then player p3 guesses.

The code `p1.guess()` instructs player p1 to make a guess.  In response, player p1 stores the guess in a class member variable named `number`.  The code `guessp1 = p1.number` is the game engine retrieving player p1's guess and storing it in a local variable named `guessp1`.

Answer (score 0):

Player is an Object and i assume guess() is a method in the player object that is generating a random number between 1 and 10 and saving it in the number variable of player just like targetNumber was generated. Then p1.number etc is calling the number that was generated for that specific player for comparison